# Error installing Crashlytics - SSL peer handshake failed

Tags: objective-c, swift, ssl, curl, cocoapods

While trying to install Crashlytics I have received this error:

> Installing Crashlytics (3.7.2)
>
> [!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o >/var/folders/7x/kpl0j8gs4bj_7d9mtcw0_13r0000gp/T/d20160804-54108->w1kqku/file.zip https://kit->downloads.fabric.io/cocoapods/crashlytics/3.7.2/crashlytics.zip --create-dirs ->-netrc-optional
>
> % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                   Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
>    0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     >0curl: (35) SSL peer handshake failed, the server most likely requires a client >certificate to connect

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error disappeared under another OS X user account

Comment: This error also occurred for me, because my user had a "~/.curlrc" file containing the option "--insecure"

Comment: @thetrutz : Thanks so much man ! You saved my day ! I found the same file in my user directory. I deleted it and the Pods where installed perfectly !