# fatal: unable to access 'https://repositoryName': SSL peer handshake failed, the server most likely requires a client certificate to connect

Tags: git, bitbucket

When i try to clone the project i'm getting this error and i don't have idea what is happening. I  couldn't find a clear answer so if anyone have had this problem before let me know how did you solved it. Thanks!

Comment: [`~/.curlrc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761716/error-installing-crashlytics-ssl-peer-handshake-failed#comment74650253_38768303)? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SSL+peer+handshake+failed%2C+the+server+most+likely+requires+a+client+certificate+to+connect

Comment: Could you explain me with more detail, i don't understand the solution.

Comment: First, do you have a file `.curlrc`?

Comment: I don't think so: "~/.curlrc
-bash: /Users/oscarivanramireztinjaca/.curlrc: No such file or directory"

Comment: Then it's a different problem.

Comment: Do you have a client certificate that you want to use, or is this completely unexpected news?  Is this bitbucket.org, or an on-premises version?

Comment: Hi I'm having the same problem. It's sudden, have used bitbucket for yrs and suddenly seeing this unexpectedly. OscarIvan did you find any answer? @bk2204 any ideas?

Comment: I get the problem when just trying to push a commit to the existing repo (one I've pushed to many times in the past)

Answer (score 1):

I had to add an SSH keys into Bitbucket-->Personal settings, remove the local repository and clone it again through SSH option. I don't know why.

Comment: I see... did you follow this for adding to bitbucket https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/ssh-user-keys-for-personal-use-776639793.html ? How did you set up the SSH keys locally & on BB?

Comment: No, but should works. If doesn't works for you try set up  the Bitbucket credentials again: https://confluence.atlassian.com/get-started-with-bitbucket/git-setup-860009658.html

Comment: Thanks, I got it working by making keys & adding to bitbucket & cloning. Still don't know why I suddenly had this problem after using Bitbucket for years without this

Answer (score 0):

I started randomly running into this same error for a repository that was working fine previously. Switching remote URLs from the https protocol to ssh resolved the issue for me.

https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/changing-a-remotes-url

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you are looking for an explanation of why your workaround worked, it is best to copy and paste any error you encountered (with any necessary anonymizations).  Without a stack trace, it is impossible to judge which of several problems might have caused your problem.